# Do I have to pay capital gains tax if proceeds were immediately used for another investment?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, capital-gain

Let's suppose one sells an asset for a $200,000 profit after holding it for 10 year but then immediately sinks the entire sale price into another asset. Is one still expected to pay the capital gains tax? What cash is one expected to pay the taxes from?

How do tax liabilities work in this scenario?

Comment: “Oh sorry I spent all my money” was never a sufficient excuse for not paying taxes.

Comment: @Aganju I think that comment needs a "Rules for thee, not for me" footnote.

Comment: One issue related to this, I believe, is that funds that are contained within a retirement account do not have their gains taxed when selling off within it.

Comment: Can we assume the asset is subject to capital gains tax in the context in which it is held, sold, etc?  Things that would not generally be would be securities in a tax sheltered account (education, retirement, etc) or your primary residence, for example.

Comment: The LT capital gains tax is a tiny fraction of asset value. Say you invest $5000 and it grows to $10,000, you sell/buy another investment.  The gain is only $5000, and the capital gains tax is, say, 10% of that.  On a $10,000 investment, $500 is couch cushion change.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: $500 is 5% of $10,000. I wouldn't call 5% "couch cushion change".

Comment: Why wouldn't you be? Surely your asset appreciated in part because of the sort of things taxes fund.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Some of us pay long-term capital gains tax rates of 33%. For example, a California resident whose income is over $1,000,000.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz that isn't relevant to OP's question, though... At that kind of wage you hire a CPA and no need to ask lol...

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica It may not be relevant to the OP, but it's relevant to the OP's question.

Answer (score 47):

Buying another asset makes no difference, you still owe capital gains tax on the sale.

What cash should you use? If you didn't have other cash to pay the taxes you should have kept some of the cash from the sale to pay taxes and not reinvested it all.

Comment: From a theoretical standpoint, couldn't a person A create a corporation B, which does the investing, then take out the profits only once every N years or so to pay taxes on those? Presumably corporation B will have to pay taxes as well, but I believe it would be able to at least offset losses in year N with profits in year N+1 (so paying 0 taxes both years) as opposed to an individual who would pay 0 tax in year N but non zero in year N+1

Comment: @ant both corporations and individuals can claim eligible losses as reductions of income. It is not clear where the benefit of your plan is. This also doesn't seem relevant to the question or this answer in particular.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I did not know inidiviiduals could do that. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 24):

It seems to me you are thinking of the [1031 Exchange](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-news/fs-08-18.pdf) which offers deferral of the gain if the proceeds are all invested in the next property. This is for (rental) real estate, not stocks. A similar rule applied to one's home, but that law is long gone, and instead there is an exemption under certain conditions.

Answer (score 21):

You didn't mention what the asset was.

For non sheltered securities, their sale is a tax event whether it's a realized gain or loss regardless of what the holding period was or what you subsequently did with the money.

If the asset was say a property, the tax status would depend on the amount of the gain and whether it was your home or an investment property.

The IRS is not concerned with where you get the cash if taxes are due.  You owe them and it's your responsibility to pay them.

Answer (score -5):

I believe that, at least for stocks, you do not have to pay, or for that matter report CGT, if you are in the lowest tax brackets, perhaps up to 15%. I am quoting from memory, you should double check this.

Comment: While I am not somebody who cares about earning any points here, I do wonder about people who rated my answer with -5 points. My answer is correct as I double checked it. Is SE some kind of a political organization not interested in fair exchange of information and ideas? Just asking.